# Adding custom module to application

Tags: angular

I'm trying to add FormValidator Module to my app. I wanted to put some service in there. I used ng CLI to add a module and then added a service. From what I understand I need to import this module in app.module right? The plan is to use service from that module in some other parts of application.

This is first time I'm trying to create module and I am having problems to make it work. Would appreciate some help with my code sample

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dubuhr

Thank you

Comment: What is the issue you are having currently? I see a form-validator error?

Comment: Your module is currently useless, since it doesn't declare or provide anything. The error you get in the stackblitz is caused by `import { ValidateService } from 'form-validator/validate.service';`, which should be `import { ValidateService } from './form-validator/validate.service';`. Given how you try to use the service, it seems you don't understand the difference between a static and an instance method, and the principle of dependency injection. Read about it: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#injecting-services

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fix import statement and its working. I changed import statement from

```
import { ValidateService } from 'form-validator/validate.service';
```

to

```
import { ValidateService } from './form-validator/validate.service';
```

[image]